# Infinite polling with Angular 4 and Http observables

Tags: javascript, angular, long-polling, rxjs5, angular-http

I'm trying to build an infinite polling in my Http service because I'm building a king of of dashborad who survey data's comming from a servor, here's my code who's almost working (in my console I see the Json comming but it doesn't reflect to my view...I would like to inject in my users: Observable

```
const usersURL = 'http://my.super.servor.php'

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

 users: Observable<User[]>

   constructor (public http:Http) {
     this.users = http.get(usersURL)
              genre mobile ou autre
              .map(res => [res.json()]);

        let i = this.users.subscribe(
          usersURL => console.log(usersURL),
         () => {}, // Here we catch up errors
         () => console.log("completed!") // Here we catch up if its completed
        )

    // Here's where I'm trying to do the polling every 5 secondes
    let tick$ = Observable.interval(5000);

    let response$ = 
      tick$
          .flatMap(() => http.get(usersURL))
          .map(res => [res.json()]);

    let stockPoller = response$.subscribe(res => console.log(res));
  }
```

Comment: Move your http call into a method and return the observable. Then inject the service into a component, call the new method and subscribe to the result.That's it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just assign your polling observable to `this.users`:

```
this.users = tick$.flatMap(() => http.get(usersURL)).map(res => [res.json()]);
```

Comment: wooow that's work's really great many many thanks ! And another question I think you know it as well: When  I bind that observable to the view I didi it for exemple: <p class="zero4" *ngFor="let user of userService.users | async">{{user.data.apps.non_running.non_sensitive.unseen}}</p> ..but I did it almose 50 times per view and my page start to take time to load...do you know how to avoid that kind of issue??

Comment: please see my question in last comment

Comment: are you asking "if I bind 50 ui elements to the observable, how do I make them share the same polling observable instead of starting 50 individual polls"?  Just add `.publishReplay(1).refCount()` after the `.map(...)`.  That will cause the underlying polling to be shared by all bound ui elements

Comment: yes thats it  because my page is now very slow to load...I will try

Comment: the thing is I would like the first loading load the page as fast as possible then the polling start...if it is possible?

Comment: Use `publishBehavior(<User[]>[])` instead of `publishReplay(1)`.

Comment: many thanks for helps ! Your code works well but at the fist load my page wait 5 secondes to show the datas from API...

Comment: Is it possible to have a time for the first load and one for the refresh?

Comment: use `timer` instead of `interval`.  It has arguments for the "first" timer and the subsequent periodic timer.

Comment: many thanks that work very well :-)  do you know some good tuto about Rxjs library? Because I found the doc not very clear...